# JQuery clearing all text boxes

Tags: jquery, textbox, eventhandler, jquery-click-event

I have a question. I am trying to clear the text fields of a form once a button is clicked.
This is the HTML for the input type:

```
<input type="button" id="clear_entries" value="Clear Entries">
```

This is my Jquery code:

```
$("#clear_entries").click(
                    function() {                        
                        $(":text").val("");                                 
            })
```

nothing happens when I click the Clear Entries button and I am not sure why.
I have confirmed with an alert statement(which I have removed from the above snippet) within the function to confirm that the
function is being invoked.

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/w07eLn32/  Provide a runnable [mcve] that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#clear_entries").click(function(){                        
     $('input[type="text"]').val(""); 
 })
```

check the link for fiddle code

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/zhmp3ked/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#clear_entries').on('click', function () {
  $(".form input[type=text]").val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
<label for="">Name : </label> <input type="text">
<label for="">email : </label> <input type="text">
<input type="button" id="clear_entries" value="Clear Entries">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response everyone. I just realized that I made the mistake of placing this within the function meant for another button. Also just to confirm, both

```
$(":text").val("");
```

and

```
$('input[type="text"]').val("");
```

give the desired result. Thank you once again.